# VC choosing the wrong operator<< overload only at the first call. Bug?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, operator-overloading, std

I spent some time removing all the uninfluent code and here is my problem.

***--- File.h ---***

```
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

template <typename Element>
class DataOutput : public std::basic_ofstream<Element>
{
public:
    DataOutput(const std::string &strPath, bool bAppend, bool bBinary)
    : std::basic_ofstream<Element>(
        strPath.c_str(),
        (bAppend ? ios_base::app : (ios_base::out | ios_base::trunc)) |
(bBinary ? ios_base::binary : 0))
    {
        if (is_open())
            clear();
    }

    ~DataOutput()
    {
        if (is_open())
            close();
    }
};


class File 
{
public:
    File(const std::string &strPath);

    DataOutput<char> *CreateOutput(bool bAppend, bool bBinary);
private:
    std::string m_strPath;
};
```

***--- File.cpp ---***

```
#include <File.h>

File::File(const std::string &strPath)
: m_strPath(strPath)
{
}

DataOutput<char> *File::CreateOutput(bool bAppend, bool bBinary)
{
    return new DataOutput<char>(m_strPath, bAppend, bBinary);
}
```

***--- main.cpp ---***

```
#include <File.h>

void main()
{
    File file("test.txt");

    DataOutput<char> *output(file.CreateOutput(false, false));

    *output << "test"; // Calls wrong overload
    *output << "test"; // Calls right overload!!!

    output->flush();
    delete output;
}
```

And this is the output file after building with `cl` and options `/D "WIN32" /D "_UNICODE" /D "UNICODE"` and running

***--- test.txt ---***

```
00414114test
```

Basically what happens is that the first `operator<<` call in `main` is bound to the member method

```
basic_ostream<char>& basic_ostream<char>::operator<<(
    const void *)
```

whereas the second one is (correctly) bound to

```
basic_ostream<char>& __cdecl operator<<(
    basic_ostream<char>&,
    const char *)
```

thus giving a different output.

This doesn't happen if i do any of the following:

- Inline `File::CreateOutput`
- Change `DataOutput` with a non-template one with `Element=char`
- Add `*output;` before the first `operator<<`  call

Am i correct in considering this an undesired compiler behavior?

Is there any explanation for this?

Oh, and i'm using VC7 at the moment to test this simplified code but i have tried the original code in VC9 and VC8 and the same thing was happening.

Any help or even a clue is appreciated

Comment: This is a clear-cut compiler bug. It repros on VS2010 beta2 as well, by the way. As written, this is already a wonderful bug report - you can post it to https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback pretty much as is.

Comment: I will ASAP. At least i didn't waste all this time for nothing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like a compiler bug. You might want to try with the latest VC compiler (which at the moment is VC10 Beta2), and if it's not fixed, follow up with the VC team (you'll need a complete self contained repo). If it is fixed, you should just use the work around you found and move on with your life.

Comment: FWIW I repo on the latest VC10 bits as well. Looks like a compiler bug.

Answer (score 3):

It is a compiler bug (not just looks like one) since it produces different call bindings for the two identical statements

```
    *output << "test"; // Calls wrong overload
    *output << "test"; // Calls right overload!!!
```

However, ***the compiler is within its rights*** to do this, since you have

```
    void main()
```

which means that this is not a valid C++ program (`void main` isn’t permitted in C either, and it has never been valid in C or C++). So, you have been running the result of compiling invalid source code. The result of that can be anything.

The fact that the Visual C++ compiler does not diagnose `void main` is just ***another compiler bug***.

Comment: +1 for *"The fact that the Visual C++ compiler does not diagnose void main is just another compiler bug."*

Comment: Sorry, but this is wrong.  The code is *non-portable*, but the Visual C++ documentation specifically states that it is allowed (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6wd819wh.aspx)  And the C++ Standard explicitly enables implementations to accept `main` with a types in addition to `int(void)` or `int(int, char*[])`.  Microsoft arguably took it beyond what the Standard blesses, but they aren't breaking valid code so it's a legal extension.  The code is not conforming on *all* freestanding C++ implementations, but it is correct on this particular compiler.

Comment: @BenVoigt: sorry, but you're wrong. first, the practical significance: that the code won't compile with e.g. g++. the visual c++ compiler could indeedy get away with anything if it just *emitted a diagnostic* first. that's all that the standard requires of it, but, it fails to do that. so, it's not standard-conforming in this respect.

Comment: @BenVoigt: besides, you're arguing that visual c++ isn't a hosted implementation but a freestanding one. i think you're possibly not aware of what that means. but FIY, if true then that would be much much more shameful than just being a little too lenient about `main`... :-( i rather like visual c++ and i think this fanboy thing where one pretends that it's perfect, is just not very relevant, to anything. take it as it is, is my advice.,

Comment: @Alf: Ok, I got freestanding and hosted mixed up.  And there's no requirement to generate warnings for non-portable code.  For example, you wouldn't argue that a warning is required for `int main(int argc, char* argv[], char* envp[])` would you?

Comment: @Alf: Also, VS2012 at least DOES generate a diagnostic for `void main(void)`.  And has since VS2003.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1wk7h414.aspx  You are compiling with `/Za` if you're wanting maximum compliance, aren't you?  If you're worrying about non-compliance when your compile options requested non-compliance, that's PEBKAC, not a compiler bug.

Comment: @Alf: It's rubbish that if you use the compiler option (`/Ze`) for Microsoft-specific extensions, you can use Microsoft-specific extensions without a warning?  And that if you pass `/Za`, you do get a warning?  No, you're simply incorrect when you said Visual C++ didn't warn about this.

Comment: @BenVoigt: re "[is it] rubbish that ... if you pass /Za, you do get a warning?" if you compile a program that uses `<windows.h>` with option /Za, then the compilation **fails** (not warnings, errors). hence the option is ***unusable*** for any serious development work, and the notion that it could be used, is complete and utter rubbish. as i recall this "ansi" option is therefore slated for removal, if it hasn't been removed already. sorry for not having time to explain more fully a few days ago. but in short: it's rubbish. ;-)

Comment: @Alf: The compiler not working correctly with `/Za` would be a bug, but it's a very different sort of a bug than what you described.  BTW, people writing standard portable C++ code aren't using `#include <windows.h>`, so the notion that it makes `/Za` useless is just a lame excuse to avoid fixing your answer.

Comment: @BenVoigt: AFAIK you're wrong when you state that the compiler doesn't work correctly with /Za. at least, you would have to prove that it doesn't. you're wrong about /Za being a solution to the non-conformance. just apply it to any serious program you're doing, to show conclusively to yourself that that **does not work**. you're wrong about standard-conformance being relevant only to code that doesn't use any extensions. if that was true then standard conformance would be a non-issue in windows. and you're wrong about the answer needing a fix (at least, for the `void main` issue). sorry.

Comment: @Alf: Huh?  You're the one who said the compiler doesn't work correctly with `/Za`.  I said "would be a bug", subjunctive tense, speaking about a hypothetical situation.  And you just claimed *again* that `/Za` **does not work** (your words, your boldface).  Code that uses extensions is by definition non-conformant.  And using extensions is not necessary to write code in Windows.  Finally, your answer is flatly wrong because it says that MSVC doesn't generate a diagnostic for `void main()`, when it does.  I've given you plenty of time to correct it.  -1

Comment: @BenVoigt: re "using extensions is not necessary to write code in Windows", that's true of e.g. VBScript programming. for serious C++ programming it is untrue. we're not in the business of writing "Hello, world", and code that includes `<windows.h>` does not compile with option /Za. you know that, and I have told you that above. so you are (proved to be) lying.-

Comment: @BenVoigt: re "Finally, your answer is flatly wrong because it says that MSVC doesn't generate a diagnostic for void main()", you know that your statement is untrue, hence it is a lie. most evertything that you have stated in these comments has been wrong. but it's only now, after making sure that you *know* it's wrong, that it's proved that you are trying to make people believe what you yourself know is wrong.

Comment: @Alf: You apparently neglected to visit the link I gave earlier in this discussion.  This is the diagnostic Visual C++ generates: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1wk7h414.aspx  In code that includes `<windows.h>`, and therefore uses `/Ze`, `void main()` is not an error.  You're desperately trying to conflate two cases: a desire to diagnose non-portable `void main()` and a desire to use `<windows.h>` and code directly against the Win32 API.  These cases are mutually exclusive.

Comment: @BenVoigt: Visual C++ without `<windows.h>` is worthless. the compiler people refer to by "visual c++" is the one that can be used to make Windows programs. yes, there is completely unnatural interpretation in which it is literally true that something you choose to call visual c++ can diagnose `void main`, but offering that without noting that it's not the visual c++ that people think of when you say visual c++, but instead a compiler that can only compile "hello world" stuff, not noting that is just plain lying.

Comment: @BenVoigt: re "In code that includes <windows.h>, and therefore uses /Ze, void main() is not an error.", right, and the fact that it's not diagnosed makes the compiler non-conforming in this respect. C++11 §1.4/8: "A conforming implementation may have extensions (including additional library functions), provided they do
not alter the behavior of any well-formed program. Implementations are required to diagnose programs that
use such extensions that are ill-formed according to this International Standard. Having done so, however,
they can compile and execute such programs." as i stated earlier

Comment: @Alf: And that's what you get when you use `/Za`.  If you use `/Ze`, you're stating your intent to use such extensions (and silencing many of the diagnostics).  I don't see how that constitutes a compiler bug; it's perfectly reasonable behavior.

Comment: @Alf: Also, calling all portable C++ programs "hello world stuff" is just crazy.  Do I use `<windows.h>` stuff regularly?  Yes.  Do I use it in every useful non-trivial program?  No.  Most scientific software can be implemented perfectly well using only Standard C++ (and many times also standard OpenMP, which is portable and doesn't require `<windows.h>`).  When I am using `<windows.h>`, do I want diagnostics for every use of an extension?  No, that would ruin the signal-to-noise ratio and make compiler warnings useless.

Comment: @BenVoigt: re "When I am using <windows.h>, do I want diagnostics for every use of an extension?" that is very misleading statement. the C++ standard only requires a single diagnostic. and i told you so earlier, including quoting the relevant part of the C++11 standard, §1.4/8.

Comment: @BenVoigt: sorry, i'm getting so tired of refuting every new silly claim or plausible-but-incorrect argument that i'm now mixing up my own thoughts on the matter. one thing is for sure, there is enough **noise** & distraction above to suffice for several hard rock concerts.

Comment: @Alf: So, one diagnostic saying "Warning, MS extensions enabled.  Program may not be portable to other compilers." would suffice?

Answer (score 0):

change

DataOutput *output(file.CreateOutput(false, false));

to

DataOutput* output = file.CreateOutput(false, false); and it might work. But to make this a reasonable lib function you don't have to clean up after you should not return a pointer but an actual object.

Comment: Standard stream classes are non-copyable (`std::basic_ios` has private copy-constructor and copy-assignment operator), which means that with standard streams (or any streams built within the same approach) returning the stream itself by value is not an option. A smart pointer or a wrapper would work here, but that might be a different story, depending on the OP's design.

Comment: This didn't work in VC7. But there are a lot of workarounds like adding <code>*output</code> or <code>output->SomeMethod()</code> before both calls that seem to do.
As for the design part, this is not actual code, it is my attempt to reproduce the bug. In the original code that same method returns a smart pointer to a base class, and the method itself is virtual for allowing classes other than <code>File</code> to return different stream-derived objects.